# Using a COM DLL in delphi - Access violation in MSVCR80D.dll error

Tags: .net, delphi, com, dll, delphi-2006

I need to use a DLL created using .NET framework. This DLL is made COM visible.

I want to use this DLL in an application created using Delphi 2006. I have followed following steps:

1. Registered the DLL using regscr32.
2. Imported the type library using
   Delphi IDE. It created
   _TLB.pas file. Following signature was created in TLB file.

   ```
   function TValidationRequest.Process(var meterBSN: WideString; var NICSerial: WideString; 
                                       var partNumber: WideString; var otherConfig: WideString; 
                                       out returnMessage: WideString): Smallint;
   begin
     Result := DefaultInterface.Process(meterBSN, NICSerial, partNumber, otherConfig, returnMessage);
   end;
   ```
3. I tried to call the method using
   following code snippet.

```
procedure TForm1.buttonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  valReq: TValidationRequest;
  s1, s2, s3, s4, s5: WideString;
  o: WideString;
begin
  valReq := TValidationRequest.Create (Self);
  try
    valReq.Process (s1, s2, s3, s4, o);
    MessageDlg(o, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
  finally
    valReq := nil;
  end;
end;
```

But I get following error when Process method is called.
[image]

Please can you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try initializing the `WideStrings` (`s1`,`s2`,`s3`,`s4`, and maybe even `o`). If I recall correctly, they are dynamic in Delphi and nil (000000000) before you set them up.

Comment: You rock MarkusQ! Thanks a lot.

I would have given you 100 votes if I could. :)

Comment: Nice job! That was what I spotted when I looked at it, too. @Hermant: For future use, remember that local vars (declared in a method body) are for the most part (strings excepted) not initialized and can contain anything. Vars declared globally or as member fields of a class are set to defaults.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what MarkusQ said, note that your memory management of the `TValidationRequest` object is not so good. It would be cleaner to use `Create(nil)` and then in the `finally`-block write `FreeAndNil(valReq)`.  The way it is now you create one `TValidationRequest` object every time you click the button and they will all stay in memory until you destroy the form. At least you won't get memory leaks because you passed `Self` to the constructor so at least the form will take care of destroying those objects. In your example there is really no need to keep the object alive after the `TForm1.buttonClick` method has ended.

Comment: Fully agree with your point. Actually I created the code snippet for better understanding of the question. It is not part of my production code :)
Thanks for pointing out though!